# Solve equation $\lim_{n \to \infty}\cos (nx)=1$

Tags: calculus

> Solve equation $\lim_{n \to \infty}\cos(nx)=1$

Ok,  $ \cos0 = 1$, but $0\times \infty \neq 0$

So, i think $x = \frac{0}{n}$ will work:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\cos(n \times \frac{0}{n})=\lim_{n \to \infty}\cos(0\times1)=1$$

I'm right?

Comment: but $\frac 0n=0$ for every nonzero $n$

Comment: I am pretty sure $x$ is supposed to be independent of $x$, so that setting $x=0/n$ (which makes the $x$ in the limit change in every term) is disallowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not right enough.

In fact, $x=2k\pi$ for any $k\in Z$. (Note that $x=\frac0n=0$.)

Comment: The only point that is consistently 1 is x=0. Any others will range over [-1,1] and have no limit.

Answer (score 1):

**x = 0 is the only solution.** Here's why.

Applying one of the definitions of a limit ($*$): $$\lim_{n \to \infty} cos\ nx = 1 \iff \forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists \delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0 \ s.t. \ \forall n>\delta: \ |cos \ nx - 1 | < \epsilon $$

If $x = 0$, ($*$) follows by inspection.

If $x \neq 0$, let's assume that ($*$) holds. Take a subsequence of $n$ of the form 
$$ n_i = \frac{2\pi i + \frac{\pi}{2}}{x}$$
Obviously $n_i \to \infty $ as $i \to \infty$. Moreover, $\forall \epsilon < 1, \ \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$: $$|cos \ n_i x - 1| = \Big|cos \Big(2\pi i + \frac{\pi}{2}\Big) - 1 \Big| = \Big|cos \Big(\frac{\pi}{2}\Big) - 1 \Big| = |0 - 1| = 1 > \epsilon, $$
which breaks ($*$) . Hence any $x\neq 0$ is not a solution to this problem.